# what is wrong with this vector coding?(beginner)

Tags: c++, vector

i want to make a loop to display elements in the vectors from the first one and the next one, second one and the next one, third one and the next one till the last one. however when i run this the error pops up saying vector subscript out of range...any advice please
I am beginner.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vecB.size(); i++)
{
    cout << vecB[i]; cout << " "; cout << vecB[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize the vector? What's in it?

Answer (score 5):

If `vecB.size()` is, for example 5, then on the last iteration of the loop, `i` will be 4. This will be the last value of `i`, on the last iteration of your `for` loop. Now take the body of this loop:

```
cout << vecB[i]; cout << " "; cout << vecB[i + 1];
```

And try to figure out, using paper in pencil, whether any of the vector references here will be out of range. Remember, that `vecB` contains five elements, `vecB[0]` through `vecB[4]`. And, as I explained, `i` will be 4.

The clock starts ticking ...**now**.

Answer (score 1):

On the last iteration of the loop you display the last item and the one after it which does not exist hence the error

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine `vecB.size() == 3`

And let's go through the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i != vecB.size(); ++i)
    cout << vecB.at(i) << " " << vecB.at(i + 1);
    //              0                      1

for (int i = 0; i != vecB.size(); ++i)
    cout << vecB.at(i) << " " << vecB.at(i + 1);
    //              1                      2

for (int i = 0; i != vecB.size(); ++i)
    cout << vecB.at(i) << " " << vecB.at(i + 1);
    //              2                      3! out of range!
```

You could fix this by checking `i != vecB.size() - 1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i != v.size() - 1; ++i)
    cout << v.at(i) << " " << v.at(i + 1) << '\n';
```